# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Combine results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a pretty simple table. It has a key column and 4 further columns each denoting a different datatype. The rules are this:

1. Each row has a completed key value
2. For each row the 4 remaining columns might be all empty
   or
3. For each row only 1 of the 4 remaining columns will be populated

What I'm trying to achieve is to write a query which will result in two columns only (the key and the 1 of the 4). Essentially condensing the 4 columns ito one.

The datatypes of the 4 columns is as follows:

```
nvarchar(255)
numeric(32, 5)
datetime
nvarchar(MAX)
```

Source Data

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦══════╦════════════╦════════════════╗
║ key ║   col1    ║ col2 ║    col3    ║      col4      ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬══════╬════════════╬════════════════╣
║   1 ║ some text ║ null ║ null       ║ null           ║
║   2 ║ null      ║ 5    ║ null       ║ null           ║
║   3 ║ null      ║ null ║ null       ║ null           ║
║   4 ║ null      ║ null ║ 23/02/2017 ║ null           ║
║   5 ║ null      ║ null ║ null       ║ much more text ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩══════╩════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Ideal Output

```
╔═════╦════════════════╗
║ key ║     newCol     ║
╠═════╬════════════════╣
║   1 ║ some text      ║
║   2 ║ 5              ║
║   3 ║ null           ║
║   4 ║ 23/02/2017     ║
║   5 ║ much more text ║
╚═════╩════════════════╝
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What do you want the output to be like?  A column in a result set has only one type.

Answer (score 2):

The `coalesce()` function can work, but only if you convert all the values to strings:

```
select id,
       coalesce(col1,
                cast(col1 as nvarchar(255)),
                cast(col2 as nvarchar(255)),
                cast(col3 as nvarchar(255))
               ) as col
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COALESCE` like this

```
select id, coalesce(cast(column1 as nvarchar(255)), cast(column2 as nvarchar(255)), cast(coulmn3 as nvarchar(255)), cast(column4 as nvarchar(255)) 
from ...
```

If they are all `NULL` then `NULL` will be returned. Otherwise, if we are guaranteed to have only one of the four columns `NOT NULL` then this one will be returned.

Comment: I believe this answer will return a type conversion error.  I understand the answer, but not the upvote.

Comment: Gordon is right. I have corrected the answer but his should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **isnull**.

```
select key, isnull(col1,col2,col3,col4) as newCol ......
```

Using COALESCE may create problem sometimes due to **data type precedence**. Since COALESCE determines the type of the output based on data type precedence.

Check the below link for more details.

[Reference](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/)